# have python process run similar to how redis process does (in the background)

Tags: python, process, redis, bottle

I asked this question on `superuser`, but haven't gotten a response. Maybe here would of been more appropriate.

When I start my redis server with `redis-server`, even after I close the terminal or logout the process will still be there when I log back in, but my python bottle server `python server.py` will turn off if I close to terminal or logout. How do I get similar behavior as redis in python.

Comment: There is Apache+Mod_WSGI or Cherrypy server and other standalone WSGI servers which run in daemon mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to run the process through screen or tmux.

You could also try doing something with e.g. [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) on Unix, or various other approaches for running daemons.

Comment: cool, I was reading up on this and I saw another solution that uses `nohup`, what is the difference/advantages between using a `python-daemon` and using `nohup python server.py`?